# Can non-type template parameters in c++17 be decltype(auto)?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17

I discovered that gcc and clang allow to use `decltype(auto)` in non-type template parameter type clause. E.g.:

```
template <decltype(auto)>
struct X {};

int foo ;

int main() {
    X<(foo)> x;
    static_cast<void>(x);
}
```

[[live demo gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WjMznykm1OHne1WP) [[live demo clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MTmKJb5JOmsOfeJx)

Is it standard compliant feature or is it some gnu extension?

Comment: This is why I stay up late on SO. Such questions are what makes me learn more about the language myself :)

Comment: @StoryTeller I admit that, at least for me, c++ is still full of surprises :)

Comment: Very nice question. +1 And, @StoryTeller: I agree with you definetely.

Comment: `(foo)` is deduced as `int &`, which is known at compile time as `foo` is a global variable (with static storage duration). I didn't realise at first what was happening here.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is standard. First, for a non-type template parameter:

[[temp.param/4]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#4)

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following
>   (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - ...
> - a type that contains a **placeholder type**.

Where placeholder types have the following specified:

[[dcl.spec.auto/1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#1)

> **The auto and decltype(auto) type-specifiers are used to designate a
>   placeholder type** that will be replaced later by deduction from an
>   initializer. The auto type-specifier is also used to introduce a
>   function type having a trailing-return-type or to signify that a
>   lambda is a generic lambda ([expr.prim.lambda.closure]). The auto
>   type-specifier is also used to introduce a structured binding
>   declaration.

[[dcl.spec.auto/5]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#1)

> **A placeholder type can also be used** in the type-specifier-seq in the
>   new-type-id or type-id of a new-expression and **as a decl-specifier of
>   the parameter-declaration's decl-specifier-seq in a
>   template-parameter.**

Since the bullet above says "placeholder type", and such a type can be designated either with `auto` or `decltype(auto)`, both compilers are correct.