# Is there a way to make template auto deduce a reference?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I'm trying to write a struct that can take both a template non-type value and a template non-type referece. For example, in C++14, I can achieve this with:

```
template <typename T, T val> struct S{};
```

This way, I can instantiate

```
S<int, 10> s;
```

or

```
static constexpr double d = 10.0;
S<const double&, d> s;
```

I'm wondering if this can be achieved with the C++17 `template auto` syntax at all. If I try,

```
template <auto val> struct S{};
```

Then, I can instantiate S<10>, but I'm at loss of how to instantiate the `const double&` version. However, if I do,

```
template <auto& val> struct S{};
```

I can instantiate `S<d>` but not `S<10>`. Is there a way to make `auto` work for both? I've been trying to SFINAE stuff to inherit from my C++14 version but it seems like there's no way to use metaprogramming to check if something passed into `auto val` is a reference or not.

Edit: This has been solved. See the comment below.

Comment: Have you considered `decltype(auto)`?

Comment: Works for me. Wow I didn't know I could do `template <decltype(auto) val>`

Comment: Well I I wasn't sure until I've [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027276/can-non-type-template-parameters-in-c17-be-decltypeauto)

Comment: Closed as duplicate; remember, closed as duplicate doesn't mean "you did something wrong", it just means "this other Q&A answers your question, why would we put another answer here".