# Why instantiation of my template with non-type template parameter leads to compilation error if instantiated with reference?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, clang++

I have `value_list` struct template:

```cpp
template <decltype(auto)... values>
struct value_list
{};
```

and I want to implement a method to be able to access template parameter by index.
So I ended up with this solution:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

namespace details
{
// Second parameter T is just to get rid of errors like this:
// Ambiguous partial specializations of 'at_impl<0, value_list<1>>'
template <std::size_t I, typename T, typename ValueList>
struct at_impl;

template <decltype(auto) Head, decltype(auto)... Rest>
struct at_impl<0, void, value_list<Head, Rest...>>
{
    static constexpr decltype(auto) value = Head;
};

template <std::size_t I, decltype(auto) Head, decltype(auto)... Rest>
struct at_impl<I, int, value_list<Head, Rest...>>
{
    static constexpr decltype(auto) value = at_impl<I-1, std::conditional_t<I-1 == 0, void, int>, value_list<Rest...>>::value;
};
}  // namespace details

template <std::size_t I, typename ValueList>
struct at
{
    static constexpr decltype(auto) value = details::at_impl<I, std::conditional_t<I == 0, void, int>, ValueList>::value;
};

template <std::size_t I, typename ValueList>
inline constexpr decltype(auto) at_v = at<I, ValueList>::value;
```

which can be used like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define LOG(x) \
std::cout << #x << ": " << x << '\n'

int main()
{
    static constexpr int i = 5;
    const std::size_t index = 0;
    LOG((at_v<index, value_list<i>>));
    
    return 0;
}
```

output: `(at_v<index, value_list<i>>): 5`

But the problem is that it does not compile if we instantiate `value_list` template with reference as argument:

```cpp
int main()
{
    static constexpr int i = 5;
    const std::size_t index = 0;

    constexpr const int & ri = i;
    LOG((at_v<index, value_list<ri>>));
    
    return 0;
}
```

error: `implicit instantiation of undefined template 'details::at_impl<0, void, value_list<i>>'`

Why `at_impl` does not compile if `value_list` contains reference and how to fix this?

Here is [link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pJwCy7yioOMiTLPa) to wanbox if you wish to play with my code.

Comment: Perhaps [Using decltype(auto) in C++ non-type template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64415853/using-decltypeauto-in-c-non-type-template-parameter) or [Can non-type template parameters in c++17 be decltype(auto)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027276/can-non-type-template-parameters-in-c17-be-decltypeauto) provides enough info. Not really sure. Fwiw, g++ accepts your code, but I'm not sure it should - and using Sam's trick, `LOG((at_v<index, value_list<+ri>>));`, makes it work in clang++ too (but of course requires unary plus to be available for the type).

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you for valuable info. I use `AppleClang 14.0.0.14000029` and trick with `+` helped me get my code compiled but it does not look like common solution and besides that `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(at_v<0, value_list<+ri>>), const int>);` tells me that deduced type of `ri` is just `const int` but not `const int &` as I expected. So now I think that appropriate solution would be to implement it somehow without `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: You're welcome! No, I don't see how the unary plus would really help in case you actually want the reference type. It's an interesting problem. I hope Sam (who wrote both the other answers) comes along to take a look at this question too :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes it would be great if he answer my question. But currently I have come up with worked solution which uses `std::tuple` and `std::tuple_element_t`

Comment: The way `decltype(auto)` template parameters are supposed to work is underspecified. I think implementors have basically just guessed, and all implementations appear to be buggy in different ways, except EDG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that at least I figured out how to fix my code to make it work identically under all three major compilers(msvc, gcc and clang). But template `at` in this case should be inside `value_list`:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <decltype(auto)... Values>
struct value_list
{
    template <std::size_t I>
    using at_t = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<decltype(Values)...>>;

    template <std::size_t I>
    static constexpr at_t<I> at_v = std::get<I>(std::tuple<decltype(Values)...>(Values...));
};

int main()
{
    static constexpr int i = 5;
    constexpr const int & ri = i;
    
    using list = value_list<'t', ri, i, 10>;
    
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(list::at_v<0>), const char>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(list::at_v<1>), const int &>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(list::at_v<2>), const int>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(list::at_v<3>), const int>);
    static_assert(list::at_v<0> == 't');
    static_assert(list::at_v<1> == 5);
    static_assert(list::at_v<2> == 5);
    static_assert(list::at_v<3> == 10);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<list::at_t<0>, char>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<list::at_t<1>, const int &>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<list::at_t<2>, int>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<list::at_t<3>, int>);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have checked that this code successfully compiles by:

- x64 msvc v19.38
- AppleClang 14.0.0.14000029
- GCC 12.3.0

Concerning to "why" code provided in my question does not compile I don't have better answer than "unlike gcc and msvc for some reason clang++ cannot compile this code".

**As side note:**
After reading [one of the Sam's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64416537/15659857) provided by @TedLyngmo in comment section I still do not get why `static_assert(std::is_same_v<list::at_t<2>, int>);` got compiled? Because parameter with index 2 is `i` which is unparenthesized id-expression(am I wrong?) then according to the C++17 standard `decltype(i)` should be type of the entity named by `i`. And as we can clearly see that type is `const int`(not `int`) because `constexpr` implies `const`. But in the same time I doubt that all three major compilers can be wrong. Rather I don't take something into account and this is subject for another question.